# Image orientation changed while uploading to amazon server

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, universal-image-loader

I am uploading an `image` to the `amazon server`. Everything works well but only on few devices the `orientation` changes to `landscape`. At the time of uploading the  orientation changes on a few Samsung devices and tablets. I have tried to fix it but nothing seems to be working. Below mentioned is my code.

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            value = true;

            viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Uri takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName); //get the uri of the photo in order to get the path.
            System.out.println("URI==" + takenPhotoUri);
            al.add(takenPhotoUri);

            Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());


            final int maxSize = 1560;
            int outWidth, outHeight;
            int inWidth = takenImage.getWidth();
            int inHeight = takenImage.getHeight();
            if (inWidth > inHeight) {
                outHeight = maxSize;
                outWidth = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
            } else {
                outHeight = maxSize;
                outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
            }

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


            takenImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(takenImage, outWidth, outHeight, false);
            String newDate = sdf.format(new Date());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(takenImage); //bmp is the bitmap to dwaw into

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setTextSize(30);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
            canvas.drawText(newDate, 200, 100, paint);

            //Creating a byte array output stream which is used to store the image once it has been compressed.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //Compress the image and store it in our ByteArrayOutPutStream
            takenImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);

            int rotate = 0;
            try {

                getContentResolver().notifyChange(takenPhotoUri, null);
                File imageFile = new File(String.valueOf(al.get(0)));


                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                        imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_SECRET_KEY));
                byte[] contentBytes = bos.toByteArray(); //Create a byte array to store the size of the stream.

                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes);

                Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);

                objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);

                myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
                myAsyncTask.execute();

                responseUrl += s3Client.getResourceUrl(BUCKET_NAME, photoFileName) + " ";
                System.out.println("URL IS +==========" + responseUrl);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Add the path of the image to the array list and pass it to our custom adapter.
            bitmapArrayList.add(takenImage);


            imageSwipeAdapter = new ImageSwipeAdapter(this, iv, bitmapArrayList, viewPager, this, al,
                    viewPagerLayout, cameraBtn);
            viewPager.setAdapter(imageSwipeAdapter);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

My `AsyncTask` is uploading the image in the background.

Comment: You can safely rule out the upload process and S3 itself. The problem is somewhere else. Have you considered the possibility that the device's code is just writing incorrect exif data, causing you to rotate an image when you shouldn't, or not rotate it when you should?  It seems like you'd want to add some logging inside `switch (orientation)` so that you actually know what your code thinks needs to be done.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, your right. The bitmap is rotated but the actual image that I capture and store, is normal. How can I make sure that the bitmap does not change its orientation? and remains portrait always?

Comment: After executing `Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());` this line the image changes it's orientation.